# How to move npm modules from registry to local machine

Tags: npm

I have project that is using npm. Some of the dependencies exist in a registry that can only be accessed over a VPN. Getting on the VPN can be onerous for developers and build machines so we don't want to require people to be on it while running `npm install`.

In order to solve this, I had created a directory called `node_modules_local`. I installed the VPN-specific dependencies while connected to the VPN then moved them to the `node_modules_local` folder. I updated `package.json` look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "dep_1": "file:node_modules_local/dep_1",
    "dep_2": "file:node_modules_local/dep_2",
    ...
}
```

After that, running `npm install` installed everything without requiring VPN access. It seems to work, but is this a valid approach?

I'm using node 8.7.0 and npm 5.4.2 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My team and I use [Yarn](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) for this because it's easy to set up an offline mirror.

1. Pull down your packages into some directory  (e.g. `@angular-core-7.2.0.tgz`)
2. [Set up an offline mirror](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/) `yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror C:\my\local\repo`
3. Run `yarn install --offline --freeze-lockfile` to download the dependencies from the offline mirror

You may need to run `yarn install --offline` to generate a `yarn.lock` file before running with the `--freeze-lockfile` option.